# Getting a NoMethodError for user_id, but only on deploy (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

This is working perfectly in production, but keeps messing up on deploy. Strange thing is that I have another model set up similarly with the same code, and it works fine on deploy.

Controller:

```
  def new
        @task = Task.new
      end

    def create
        @task = Task.new(task_params)
        @task.user_id = current_user[:id]
        respond_to do |format|
          if @task.save
            format.html { redirect_to line_url(@task.lines_id), notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :lines_id, :scene, :icon, :icon_color, :fulltext, :doclink, :user_id)
    end
  end
```

Error:

```
2016-05-09T19:09:50.769530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/tasks/new?lines_id=9" host=pacific-tor-26709.herokuapp.com request_id=3dc355bb-90b3-4aac-b93d-330f5cb1561c fwd="72.24.207.125" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=126ms status=200 bytes=11300
2016-05-09T19:09:53.112272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/tasks" host=pacific-tor-26709.herokuapp.com request_id=8ddd3304-7a25-4378-94c3-efc87fb4ac07 fwd="72.24.207.125" dyno=web.1 connect=18ms service=81ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-05-09T19:09:53.050151+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/tasks" for 72.24.207.125 at 2016-05-09 19:09:53 +0000
2016-05-09T19:09:53.100064+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms
2016-05-09T19:09:53.107108+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-09T19:09:53.107138+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-09T19:09:53.073387+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gRLRjpaHGhNWLsJP4HpWb8Yv0hgjLLa0dTzQgSSb6MI=", "task"=>{"icon_color"=>"", "scene"=>"0", "title"=>"test", "description"=>"", "fulltext"=>"", "doclink"=>"", "icon"=>"", "priority"=>"9", "lines_id"=>"9"}, "commit"=>""}
2016-05-09T19:09:53.107137+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:28:in `create'
2016-05-09T19:09:53.107139+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-09T19:09:53.107135+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for #<Task:0x007fe6f34a60c8>):
2016-05-09T19:09:53.073169+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
```

Meanwhile, in production, there is no issue with the commit:

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-09 13:18:38 -0600
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tCxI70ziZPsxsJQB1PCqHFBrA8KIlnqNOPdsDoUnElE=", "task"=>{"icon_color"=>"", "scene"=>"0", "title"=>"B", "description"=>"", "fulltext"=>"", "doclink"=>"", "icon"=>"", "priority"=>"2", "lines_id"=>"11"}, "commit"=>""}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("created_at", "description", "doclink", "fulltext", "icon", "icon_color", "lines_id", "priority", "scene", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-05-09 19:18:38.261089"], ["description", ""], ["doclink", ""], ["fulltext", ""], ["icon", ""], ["icon_color", ""], ["lines_id", 11], ["priority", 2], ["scene", "f"], ["title", "B"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-09 19:18:38.261089"], ["user_id", 1]]
   (133.6ms)  commit transaction
```

I double checked to make sure I had run rake db:migrate on deploy.

I do not think it is an issue with current_user as I am definitely logged in as a user – I would not even be able to access the new form as I'm requiring current_user to view the form.

Really appreciate any insight you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to add `user_id` as hidden field in new form like :

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
```

OR a better way to do it like :

```
@task = current_user.task.new(task_params)
```

as it is a better approach & will avoid this error situation.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely works. I wanted to avoid having user id set in the form as even with it hidden you can still alter the value through something like the developer console, but this will definitely work. I just wish I could figure out why setting the user id in the controller was working for one of my models but not the other.

Comment: then do it like `@task = current_user.task.new(task_params)`